# I want this component as PDF when I click on Create PDF button It is a LWC Component If anyone have any Idea please share with me

Tags: salesforce, lwc, lightning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3oj0.jpg)

I want this component as PDF when I click on Create PDF button It is a LWC Component If anyone have any Idea please share with me

Solution and Approach Or if you'll provide me 'Technical Solution' it'll be highly appreciated